# ASP.net VB Gridview Update cast values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have a GridView with datasource from the MS Access database. 
It is

> SELECT * FROM [TODO] ORDER BY [Name]

The UPDATE query is

> UPDATE [TODO] SET [Staff] = CInt(@Staff), [Title] = @Title, [Deadline]
>   = @Deadline, [Status] = CInt(@Status) WHERE [todoID] = @ID

Two of the returned values are foreign keys (integer) for another tables - Status and Staff
So I replaced two EditItemTemplates with DropDownLists, assigning them other DataSources and binding the selected index to the foreign key.

This results in GridView generating this HTML:

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$DropDownList1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_DropDownList1_0">
                <option value="1">John Doe</option>
                <option value="2">William Jenkins</option>
                <option value="3">Kate Piper</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="4">Alison Fisher</option>

</select>
```

And this results in the following ASP.NET error when updating the record

> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Invalid use of
>   Null

I also tried not to cast values in the query - still no success, but another error is thrown:

> Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.

I am really new in ASP.NET, all my experience is based on other languages. I will really appreciate any help